# How to change the function signature in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

In other documentation systems, such as LuaDoc, there is a `@brief` directive lets you define a custom name for every token that is used intesd of the actual token name.

For example, you could have a function implemented as `foo` that will show as `bar` in the documentation.

This can be really handy if your source code passes through some kind of non-standard preprocessor before being compiled.

Or if your want to use Doxygen with a language that is not supported by Doxygen and you have to use a filter script to transform it into something Doxygen can parse.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior (renaming tokens for the docs only) in Doxygen?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here.  The body is not a question, and the title is too vague.

Comment: "Or if your want to use Doxygen with a language that is just not supported by Doxygen." If the language is not supported by Doxygen, then it's... not supported by Doxygen. So why would you use Doxygen with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter input files using `INPUT_FILTER` (same filter for all files), or `FILTER_PATTERNS` (filter for a specific extension).

Normally the source code view (i.e. `SOURCE_BROWSER=YES`) will not be processed, but you can change this using `FILTER_SOURCE_FILES=YES` and use this in combination with `FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS` if you want to use a different filter for the source code than for the documentation.

If you use a pass-through filter for the sources and a token rename filter for documentation, you should be able to get the effect that you are looking for.